# End flow/coroutines task before go further null issue

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlin-coroutines, coroutine, kotlin-flow

Fragment

```
   private fun makeApiRequest() {
        vm.getRandomPicture()
        var pictureElement = vm.setRandomPicture()

        GlobalScope.launch(Dispatchers.Main) {
            // what about internet
            if (pictureElement != null && pictureElement!!.fileSizeBytes!! < 400000) {

                Glide.with(requireContext()).load(pictureElement!!.url)
                    .into(layout.ivRandomPicture)
                layout.ivRandomPicture.visibility = View.VISIBLE
            } else {
                getRandomPicture()
            }
        }
    }
```

viewmodel

```
    fun getRandomPicture() {
        viewModelScope.launch {
            getRandomPictureItemUseCase.build(Unit).collect {
                pictureElement.value = it
                Log.d("inspirationquotes", "VIEWMODEL $pictureElement")
                Log.d("inspirationquotes", "VIEWMODEL VALUE ${pictureElement.value}")
            }
        }
    }

    fun setRandomPicture(): InspirationQuotesDetailsResponse? {
            return pictureElement.value
    }
```

Flow UseCase

```
class GetRandomPictureItemUseCase @Inject constructor(private val api: InspirationQuotesApi): BaseFlowUseCase<Unit, InspirationQuotesDetailsResponse>() {
    override fun create(params: Unit): Flow<InspirationQuotesDetailsResponse> {
        return flow{
            emit(api.getRandomPicture())
        }
    }
}
```

My flow task from viewmodel doesn't goes on time. I do not know how to achieve smooth downloading data from Api and provide it further.
I was reading I could use runBlocking, but it is not recommended in production as well.
What do you use in your professional applications to achieve nice app?

Now the effect is that that image doesn't load or I have null error beacause of my Log.d before GlobalScope in Fragment (it is not in code right now).

One more thing is definding null object I do not like it, what do you think?

```
    var pictureElement = MutableStateFlow<InspirationQuotesDetailsResponse?>(null)
```

EDIT:

Viewmodel

```
 val randomPicture: Flow<InspirationQuotesDetailsResponse> = getRandomPictureItemUseCase.build(Unit)
```

fragment

```
private fun makeApiRequest() = lifecycleScope.launch {
            vm.randomPicture
                .flowWithLifecycle(lifecycle, Lifecycle.State.STARTED)
                .collect { response ->
                    if (response.fileSizeBytes < 600000) {
                        Log.d("fragment", "itGetsValue")
                        Glide.with(requireContext()).load(response.url)
                            .into(layout.ivRandomPicture)
                        layout.ivRandomPicture.visibility = View.VISIBLE
                    } else {
                        onFloatingActionClick()
                    }
                }
    }
```

Edit2 problem on production, another topic:
Link -> [What is the substitute for runBlocking Coroutines in fragments and activities?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70668103/what-is-the-substitute-for-runblocking-coroutines-in-fragments-and-activities)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, don't use `GlobalScope` to launch a coroutine, it is highly discouraged and prone to bugs. Use provided [`lifecycleScope`](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/lifecycle/package-summary#lifecyclescope) in `Fragment`:

```
lifecycleScope.launch {...}
```

Use `MutableSharedFlow` instead of `MutableStateFlow`, `MutableSharedFlow` doesn't require initial value, and you can get rid of nullable generic type:

```
val pictureElement = MutableSharedFlow<InspirationQuotesDetailsResponse>()
```

But I guess we can get rid of it.

Method `create()` in `GetRandomPictureItemUseCase` returns a `Flow` that emits only one value, does it really need to be `Flow`, or it can be just a simple `suspend` function?

Assuming we stick to `Flow` in `GetRandomPictureItemUseCase` class, `ViewModel` can look something like the following:

```
val randomPicture: Flow<InspirationQuotesDetailsResponse> = getRandomPictureItemUseCase.build(Unit)
```

And in the `Fragment`:

```
private fun makeApiRequest() = lifecycleScope.launch {
    vm.randomPicture
      .flowWithLifecycle(lifecycle, State.STARTED)
      .collect { response ->
          // .. use response
      }
}
```

Dependency to use `lifecycleScope`:

```
implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-runtime-ktx:2.4.0'
```

Comment: Sergey it is beatiful I just edit my code to show really it is amaazing.
View model now is only one line!

Comment: Sergey, I have added this solution to my production code and I do not now why, but unfortunately it doesn't wait to finish checking the data as well I have use the same UseCase as in topic also with flow returning. I make Edit2 if you can look, thanks.

Comment: Is this another case and problem? If yes please create another question here on Stackoverflow so others can also see it.

Comment: done, thanks https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70668103/what-is-the-substitute-for-runblocking-coroutines-in-fragments-and-activities