# What is the substitute for runBlocking Coroutines in fragments and activities?

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlin-coroutines, coroutine, kotlin-flow

It is recommended to not use GlobalScope and runBlocking.
I have implemented changes in order to this topic:
[End flow/coroutines task before go further null issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70645376/end-flow-coroutines-task-before-go-further-null-issue/70645705?noredirect=1#comment124923912_70645705)

However it doesn't work well as previously with runBlocking. In brief icon doesn't change, data is not on time.
My case is to change icon depending on the boolean.

usecase with Flow

```
class GetNotificationListItemDetailsUseCase @Inject constructor(private val notificationDao: NotificationDao): BaseFlowUseCase<Unit, List<NotificationItemsResponse.NotificationItemData>>() {
    override fun create(params: Unit): Flow<List<NotificationItemsResponse.NotificationItemData>> {
        return flow{
            emit(notificationDao.readAllData())
        }
    }
}
```

viewmodel

```
    val actualNotificationList: Flow<List<NotificationItemsResponse.NotificationItemData>> = getNotificationListItemDetailsUseCase.build(Unit)
```

fragment

```
    private fun getActualNotificationList() : Boolean {
        lifecycleScope.launch {
            vm.actualNotificationList
                .flowWithLifecycle(lifecycle, Lifecycle.State.STARTED)
                .collect { response ->
                    notificationData.value = response
                    val notificationDataString = notificationData.value.toString()
                    val stringToCheck = "isRead=false"
                    isNotificationNotRead = (notificationDataString.contains(stringToCheck))
                }
        }
        return isNotificationNotRead
    }
```

on method onViewCreated I have initToolbar to check if it's true and make action, with runBlokcing worked.

```
fun initToolbar{
        if (onReceived) {
            Log.d("onReceivedGoes", "GOES IF")
        } else {
            Log.d("onReceivedGoes", "GOES ELSE")
            getActualNotificationList()
        }
        onReceived = false

        val item = menu.findItem(R.id.action_notification_list)
        when {
            isNotificationNotRead && !isOutcomed -> {
                item.setIcon(R.drawable.image_icon_change)
            }
}
```

coroutine job before change, it worked well

```
        val job = GlobalScope.launch {
            vm.getNotificationListItemDetailsUseCase.build(Unit).collect {
                notificationData.value = it
                val notificationDataString = notificationData.value.toString()
                val stringToCheck = "isRead=false"
                isNotificationNotRead = (notificationDataString.contains(stringToCheck))
            }
        }
        runBlocking {
            job.join()
        }
    }
```

Another question is I have the same thing to do in MainActivity, but I do not use there a flow just suspend function.

UseCase

```
class UpdateNotificationListItemUseCase @Inject constructor(private val notificationDao: NotificationDao): BaseUpdateBooleanUseCase<Int, Boolean, Boolean, Boolean, Unit>() {
    override suspend fun create(itemId: Int, isRead: Boolean, isArchived: Boolean, isAccepted: Boolean){
        notificationDao.updateBooleans(itemId, isRead, isArchived, isAccepted)
    }
}
```

MainActivity

```
            val job = GlobalScope.launch { vm.getIdWithUpdate() }
            runBlocking {
                job.join()
            }
```

MainViewmodel

```
suspend fun getIdWithUpdate() {
        var id = ""
        id = notificationAppSessionStorage.getString(
            notificationAppSessionStorage.getIncomingKeyValueStorage(),
            ""
        )
        if (id != "") {
           
            updateNotificationListItemUseCase.build(id.toInt(), true, false, false)
        }
    }
}
```

EDIT1:

collect in fragments works perfectly, thanks

What about MainActivity and using this usecase with suspend fun without flow.

I have read documentation https://developer.android.com/kotlin/coroutines/coroutines-best-practices

```
        val IODispatcher: CoroutineDispatcher = Dispatchers.IO
        val externalScope: CoroutineScope = CoroutineScope(IODispatcher)
            suspend {
                externalScope.launch(IODispatcher) {
                    vm.getIdWithUpdate()
                }.join()
            }
```

Second option, but here I do not wait until job is done

```
            suspend {
                withContext(Dispatchers.IO) {
                    vm.getIdWithUpdate()
                }
            }
```

What do you think about it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to update the icon in the `collect` block:

```
private fun getActualNotificationList() = lifecycleScope.launch {
        vm.actualNotificationList
            .flowWithLifecycle(lifecycle, Lifecycle.State.STARTED)
            .collect { response ->
                notificationData.value = response
                val notificationDataString = notificationData.value.toString()
                val stringToCheck = "isRead=false"
                val isNotificationNotRead = (notificationDataString.contains(stringToCheck))

                val item = menu.findItem(R.id.action_notification_list)
                when {
                    isNotificationNotRead && !isOutcomed -> {
                        item.setIcon(R.drawable.image_icon_change)
                    }
                }
            }
}
```

Using `runBlocking` you are blocking the **Main Thread**, which may cause an [ANR](https://developer.android.com/topic/performance/vitals/anr).

Comment: Thank you, it works. now I understand this collect {} much better. Would like to advice me in MainActivity case with suspend fun without flow. I have read documentation and have my proposition -> I've edited post. Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is the problem in `MainActivity `? Could you please create another question on StackOverflow and describe it in details, so others could see, thanks.

Comment: This is the same I use GlobalScope with runBlocking, but ok in some time I will put it, thanks

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70685316/how-to-manage-coroutines-in-mainactivity-with-waiting-until-done