# How to manage coroutines in MainActivity with waiting until done?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-activity, kotlin-coroutines, coroutinescope

I use `GlobalScope` with `runBlocking` in `MainActivity`, but I do not use there a flow just suspend function. I would like to change `GlobalScope` to other Scope from Coroutines.

UseCase

```
class UpdateNotificationListItemUseCase @Inject constructor(private val notificationDao: NotificationDao): BaseUpdateBooleanUseCase<Int, Boolean, Boolean, Boolean, Unit>() {
    override suspend fun create(itemId: Int, isRead: Boolean, isArchived: Boolean, isAccepted: Boolean){
        notificationDao.updateBooleans(itemId, isRead, isArchived, isAccepted)
    }
}
```

MainActivity

```
val job = GlobalScope.launch { vm.getIdWithUpdate() }
runBlocking {
    job.join()
}
```

MainViewmodel

```
suspend fun getIdWithUpdate() {
     var id = ""
     id = notificationAppSessionStorage.getString(
            notificationAppSessionStorage.getIncomingKeyValueStorage(),
            ""
        )
        if (id != "") {
           
            updateNotificationListItemUseCase.build(id.toInt(), true, false, false)
        }
    }
}
```

My proposition:

I have read documentation https://developer.android.com/kotlin/coroutines/coroutines-best-practices

```
val IODispatcher: CoroutineDispatcher = Dispatchers.IO
val externalScope: CoroutineScope = CoroutineScope(IODispatcher)
      suspend {
         externalScope.launch(IODispatcher) {
              vm.getIdWithUpdate()
         }.join()
      }
```

Second option, but here I do not wait until job is done

```
suspend {
     withContext(Dispatchers.IO) {
          vm.getIdWithUpdate()
     }
}
```

What do you think about it?
Doesn't it provide to ANR, I also block thread.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use [`lifecycleScope`](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/coroutines#lifecyclescope) in `MainActivity`, instead of `GlobalScope`, to launch a coroutine :

```
lifecycleScope.launch { 
    vm.getIdWithUpdate() // calling suspend function
    // here suspend function `vm.getIdWithUpdate()` finished execution
    // ... do something after suspend function is done
}
```

To use `lifecycleScope` add dependency:

```
implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-runtime-ktx:$2.4.0'
```

`GlobalScope` is highly discouraged to use. And there is no need to call `job.join()`, you can do something in the coroutine builder block after calling `vm.getIdWithUpdate()`, for example update UI. This coroutine is running using `Dispatchers.Main` context.

Comment: I'm not sure about this. From my perspective if I call suspend function - vm.getIdWithUpdate() - it will work as a coroutine in a background, after suspend function I could do something like navigation, but this navigation won't wait until suspend function end his work with result, when I make .job() I am 100% sure that when coroutine ends next I navigate, I know that blocks entire thread.

Comment: Could you tell me that your function works like this: -> launch scope -> call suspend function(wait until done) -> go for next parts of code in scope. So you want to tell me that also blocks but only lifecycleScope?

Comment: when you launch a coroutine (for example using `launch` builder) and call `suspend` functions in it, you don't block the Main Thread, the MainThread can still work on it's own, for example plying animation. If you want to do something after executing all `suspend` functions, you can do it at the end of the `launch` block, where I put my comment "// ... do something". `Suspend` function are executing in Background (worker) Thread and the coroutine waits for each of them. Does this answer your question?

Comment: Perfectly, thanks